# Static global variable and static local variable in driver function

Tags: c, linux, variables, static, module

In one of my sample Linux kernel module, I have a variable `Device_Open` declared static outside all functions and a static variable `counter` declared inside a function `device_open`. Inside `device_open`, i increment both `Device_Open` and `counter`. The module is inserted without any errors into the kernel and i created a device file for my module /dev/chardev.

I do `cat /dev/chardev`. What i can see is that `counter` gets incremented for each invocation of `cat /dev/chardev`, but `Device_Open` always remains 0. What is the reason for the difference in behavior related to incrementing the value of the variables ?

Below is the code snippet for understanding

```
static int Device_Open = 0;

static int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    static int counter = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Device_Open = %d", Device_Open);
    printk(KERN_INFO "counter = %d", counter);

    if (Device_Open)
        return -EBUSY;

    Device_Open++;
        counter++;

    try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not decrementing Device_Open when closing the device (when calling device_close())?

Comment: @Thanks Antti...I got the missing link.

Comment: Please spend more time reading your own code before asking questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I searched for "Device_open" and I found its corresponding device release. Are you sure you don't have this function ? I found it at [TLDP](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x892.html).

```
static int device_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    printk(KERN_INFO "device_release(%p,%p)\n", inode, file);
#endif

    /* 
     * We're now ready for our next caller 
     */
    Device_Open--;

    module_put(THIS_MODULE);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Perfect...i missed the fact that after `cat /dev/chardev` is executed, the /dev/chardev device file is closed and kernel inturn calls `device_release` to decrement the value of `Device_Open`. Thanks for reminding me the missing link.